# How to loop through nested nodes in Firebase Realtime database (java) android studio?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to loop through certain nodes of within a nested node in Firebase Realtime Database in android studio(java) .
I have provided the screenShot for the same .

I have tried to do so but it is keeping the particular activity (within which the code exists) to crash .below is my code -

```
private void setProfileModelArrayList(){
    profileFetching.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    mRealDatabase.child("users").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()){
                String name = dataSnapshot.child(documentFields.realtimeFields.fullName).getValue(String.class) ;
                if(tempUser.equals(name)){
                    dataSnapshot.getRef().child(documentFields.realtimeFields.PostedPicture).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                            String postUid = dataSnapshot.child("postUid").getValue(String.class) ;
                            String name = dataSnapshot.child("userName").getValue(String.class) ;
                            String file = dataSnapshot.child("fileName").getValue(String.class) ;
                            if(!name.isEmpty() && !file.isEmpty()) {
                                ImageModelClass imageModelClass = new ImageModelClass(postUid,name,file) ;
                                imageList.add(imageModelClass);
                                posts.setText(String.valueOf(gridView.getAdapter().getItemCount()));
                                profileFetching.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                        }
                    }) ;
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    }) ;
}
```

[image]

Comment: If there's a crash in your code, find the error message and stack trace in the logcat output, and edit your question to include that information (there's an edit link right under that). Going forward, always do this right away - you are more likely to receive help if such necessary information is included in the question from the start.

Answer (score 1):

A few rules to keep in mind:

- A `DataSnapshot` from Firebase contains all data from the path you read it from, including all data under it. You **never** should add another listener for the data under the original path, as it just complicates the code needlessly.
- Firebase calls `onCancelled` when it can't read the data. You should never ignore this error, but at the very least log it or raise it as an exception (as it typically indicates a coding error).

With this in mind, your code becomes:

```
mRealDatabase.child("users").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot userSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()){
            String uid = userSnapshot.getKey();
            Log.i("DB", "Processing data for user "+uid);
            DataSnapshot postedPicturesSnapshot = userSnapshot.child("PostedPicture");
            for (DataSnapshot postedPictureSnapshot : postedPicturesSnapshot.getChildren()){
                String postedPictureKey = postedPictureSnapshot.getKey();
                String userName = postedPictureSnapshot.child("userName").getValue(String.class);
                Log.i("DB", "Processing picture "+postedPictureKey+" from userName: "+userName);
                ...
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
        throw error.toException(); //  Never ignore errors
    }
}) ;
```

Comment: actually, that helps, thanks a lot,  I was missing the inner for loop, I appreciate your help

Comment: Good to hear Souvik.  --- It really helps to give the variables in your `for` loop good names, so that you can see immediately when you miss something in the code that *is* present in the data.